# Windowed writing with rasterio produces zeroed output

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

I am trying to create a large raster of 64-bit integers from the metadata of another file. This is done row by row, writing the output with the rasterio `Window` class. Below is a very simplified example that assigns the column number to each cell:

```py
import rasterio
from rasterio.windows import Window
import numpy as np

input_path = "/path/to/my/large/raster.vrt"
output_path = "/path/to/the/output.gtiff"

input = rasterio.open(input_path)

out_file = rasterio.open(
        output_path,
        'w',
        driver='GTiff',
        height=input.height,
        width=input.width,
        count=1,
        dtype=np.int64,
        crs=input.crs,
        transform=input.transform
    )

for j in range(input.height):

    array = np.full((input.width, 1), 10000).astype(np.int64)

    for i in range(input.width):
        array[i, 0] = i

    window = Window(0, j, array.shape[0], array.shape[1])
    out_file.write(array, window=window, indexes=1)

out_file.close()
```

This runs fine, but the output is a zeroed raster:

```bash
gdalinfo -mm /path/to/the/output.gtiff
[...]
Band 1 Block=89057x1 Type=Int64, ColorInterp=Gray
    Computed Min/Max=0.000,0.000
```

Looks like no array is ever written to the file, or that something happens to the integers sent for writing. Any clues on what I may be missing?

Comment: @user2856 could you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have rows and cols reversed, use

```
array = np.full((1, input.width), 10000).astype(np.int64)
```

and

```
array[0, i] = i
```

But note that looping through every pixel individually is a really inefficient way of doing things.

For your trivial writing column number example, you could use [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) by rows only:

```
array = np.arange(input.width, dtype=np.int64).reshape(1, input.width)
for j in range(input.height):
    window = Window(0, j, input.width, 1)
    out_file.write(array, window=window, indexes=1)
```

Or in one go using [array broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```
cols = np.arange(input.width, dtype=np.int64).reshape(1, input.width)
rows = np.zeros((input.height, 1), dtype=np.int64)
array = rows + cols
out_file.write(array, indexes=1)
```